# What is the term for a sentinel that does not denote the end of a sequence?

Tags: computer-science, terminology

As per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value),

> In computer programming, a **sentinel value** (also referred to as a flag value, trip value, rogue value, signal value, or dummy data) is a special value in the context of an algorithm which uses its presence as a condition of termination, typically in a loop or recursive algorithm.

A common example is the use of `-1` at the end of a positive integer array to denote the end of data when the array is larger than the data that fills it.

However, what about when we use `-1` not to ensure termination, but simply as an impossible value? For example:

```py
# `a` is an array with the numbers from 0 to 4, in random order.
# We will use `b` to track where in `a` each number is. The position in `b`
# denotes the number, and the value denotes the index in `a`.
# `calculate_indices()` is a function that does this.

a = [3, 4, 1, 0, 2]
b = [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1]

calculate_indices(a, b)

print(b) => [3, 2, 4, 0, 1]
```

If we were to initialize `b` as `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`, this would not work, as `0` has a real meaning here - i.e., the 0th position in `a`. Therefore we use an impossible value, `-1`.

**Is there a name for this sort of usage?**

Comment: Wikipedia's definition seems pretty strict. I've heard -1 returned by `find` functions referred to as a sentinal value before.

Comment: @Carcigenicate After [more research](https://python-patterns.guide/python/sentinel-object/#sentinel-value), it would appear you're right. If you would like to add an answer I'll accept it

Comment: I appreciate the gesture, but I don't like writing forced answers in a car like this, as it was just a hunch. This is certainly a time when self answering would be appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per Carcigenicate, and after [some](https://python-patterns.guide/python/sentinel-object/#sentinel-value) more [research](https://effbot.org/zone/default-values.htm), it would appear that Wikipedia's definition is indeed too strict, and that this can also be referred to as a sentinel. I cannot find another name for this pattern.